# Ubuntu PPA mainline kernel update - is it safe?

Tags: kernel, updates

Is safe to update kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ (to 4.1) on 15.04? How can I revert updating?

Comment: I installed 4.2 Linux kernel in 14.04.3 from that ppa.  If you have some proprietery modules you may have fail to compile them for new kernel. For example Virtualbox' module fails to compile with new kernel's header files.

Comment: @kenn I only use software repos, is there a problem?

Comment: you need to install three files from that repo, for example linux-headers-4.2.0-040200rc4-generic_4.2.0-040200rc4.201507271733_i386.deb, linux-headers-4.2.0-040200rc4_4.2.0-040200rc4.201507271733_all.deb, linux-image-4.2.0-040200rc4-generic_4.2.0-040200rc4.201507271733_i386.deb. And then you need to update grub with `sudo update-grub` You can safely update or upgrade  your kernel from that ppa.

Comment: You can pick up whatever kernel you want to boot in grub menu in boot screen.

Comment: @kenn Thanks, I'm installing it right now. (`linux-headers-4.2.0-040200-generic_4.2.0-040200.201508301530_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.2.0-040200_4.2.0-040200.201508301530_all.deb
linux-image-4.2.0-040200-generic_4.2.0-040200.201508301530_amd64.deb
`)

Comment: I got an error with proprietary Nvidia drivers `ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      `

Comment: It's because Nvidia driver source code is not updated to compile with latest headers files. You can still try to boot with it, it may boot but your graphic card performance will not be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Is safe to update kernel from [PPA mainline](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)?"**

The Mainline builds [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) clearly states that "These kernels are not supported and are not appropriate for production use."

It also states than "The mainline kernels builds are produced for debugging purposes and therefore come with no support. Use them at your own risk."

Mainline builds also don't include the Ubuntu patches normally applied to the kernel in the Ubuntu repository and alsi if there is a minimal or important security update you won't get it as you manually installed the .deb files.

**[Uninstalling](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Uninstalling_upstream_kernels) upstream kernels**

The upstream kernels have their own ABI namespace, so they install side by side with the stock Ubuntu kernels (each kernel has a separate directory under /lib/modules/VERSION for example). This means that you can keep several mainline and Ubuntu stock kernels installed at the same time and select the one you need from the GRUB boot menu.

If you would like to uninstall an upstream kernel anyway, execute the following to find the exact name of the kernel packages you want to uninstall:

dpkg -l | grep "linux-[a-z]*-"

and then execute the following to uninstall them:

sudo apt-get remove KERNEL_PACKAGES_TO_REMOVE

Remember that several packages can belong to one kernel version: common headers, architecture specific headers and the architecture specific image.

Also, once the mainline packages are removed, one may still see entries for these via the above dpkg command. To purge these entries execute at a terminal:

sudo dpkg --purge ENTRY